# SQL Pivot based on Max of one column

Tags: sql, pivot, max

I am trying to pivot out a column that has three values (1,2,3) as expected1, expected2, and expected3. I want to choose each of these values in relation to the maximum deploy time with respect to each value from the `DeployTime` column (each of the three metrics can have a different maximum deploy time, as they aren't always deployed at the same time).

Sample data will look something like this

```
CustomerNM FacilityAccountID Metric Expected DeployTime
-------------------------------------------------------
1                  1           1       1         1
1                  1           1      .5        .5
1                  1           2       2         2
1                  1           2       1         1
1                  1           3       2         2 
1                  1           3       3         3 
2                  1           1       10        15
2                  1           1       26        17
2                  1           2       25        29
2                  1           2       15        34
2                  1           3       21        7 
2                  1           3       33        2
```

I have:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID,
    MAX(DeployTime) OVER (Partition BY CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID) as DeployTime,
    [1] AS Expected1,
    [2] AS Expected2,
    [3] AS Expected3
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID, metric, expected, DeployTime
     FROM 
         TABLE) p  
PIVOT  
    (SUM (expected)
     FOR metric IN ([1], [2], [3])  
    ) AS p
```

For some reason this returns rows with only one of the new expected columns filled; essentially giving three rows when there should only be one (for each customer name/facility account ID). I think a groupby may work, but not sure.

Expected output from sample should look like

```
CustomerNM FacilityAccountID Expected1  Expected2  Expected3 
-----------------------------------------------------------
   1               1             1           2         3   
   2               1            26          15        21
```

Comment: Sample data, expected output would help here

Comment: Edited to include

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation seems so much simpler:

```
SELECT CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN metric = 1 THEN expected END) as expected1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN metric = 2 THEN expected END) as expected2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN metric = 3 THEN expected END) as expected3
FROM TABLE p
GROUP BY CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID;
```

Comment: The OP is looking for the expected values at the MAX deploy time per customer and facility...

Answer (score 0):

The key is to filter on the results you want before the pivot:

```
SELECT CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID,
MAX([1]) AS Expected1, MAX([2]) AS Expected2, MAX([3]) AS Expected3
FROM   
(SELECT CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID, metric, expected, DeployTime
FROM TABLE t
WHERE DeployTime =
(SELECT MAX(DeployTime)
 FROM TABLE t2
 WHERE t.CustomerNM = t2.CustomerNM
 AND t.metric = t2.metric
 AND t.FacilityAccountID = t2.FacilityAccountID)) p  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM (expected)
FOR metric IN  
( [1], [2], [3])  
) AS p
GROUP BY CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID
```

To Gordon's point, you could also accomplish this without the pivot and instead use a few CASE statements:

```
SELECT CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID,
MAX(CASE WHEN metric = 1 THEN expected END) as expected1,
MAX(CASE WHEN metric = 2 THEN expected END) as expected2,
MAX(CASE WHEN metric = 3 THEN expected END) as expected3
FROM TABLE t
WHERE DeployTime =
(SELECT MAX(DeployTime)
 FROM TABLE t t2
 WHERE t.CustomerNM = t2.CustomerNM
 AND t.metric = t2.metric
 AND t.FacilityAccountID = t2.FacilityAccountID)
GROUP BY CustomerNM, FacilityAccountID;
```

Tested here: http://rextester.com/JPXNU32454

Comment: Can you explain , MAX([1]) AS Expected1
, MAX([2]) AS Expected2
, MAX([3]) AS Expected3.... As these values arent always the max.

Comment: Ok I had to make some changes based on the additional data you provided. The MAX in this case is not really a MAX. It's just selecting the non NULL value following the pivot. If you try SELECT * FROM ( ) as p you will see what I mean